# Authentication just for HTTPS Requests in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, authentication

I configure the authentication for my webspace via a `.htaccess` file (I have no control over the `httpd.conf` file). For a secure implementation I have an automatic redirection of HTTP to HTTPS via

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]
```

For authentication I use the following lines

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName name
AuthUserFile ..path-to-htpasswd..
require valid-user
```

If I visit a resource via http, I have to type the user and password two times (first to get the 307-Redirection and the second time to get the actual document). Is there a way to apply authentication only for HTTPS-Request? So a HTTP request directly gets the redirection so that I would have to authenticate myself only once.

Greetings and thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take advantage of the fact that rewrites get processed before files are served with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]

<FilesMatch ".">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName name
    AuthUserFile ..path-to-htpasswd..
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

`.` is a regex wildcard so auth still applies to all valid request, but only after the rewrite occurs